# web audio soundcloud crossfade

Tags: soundcloud, web-audio-api

I'm struggling to get this basic fade-in / fade-out Web Audio code to work with SoundCloud.  It appears that the `gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime` functions are bypassed *(ie, play starts and ends at gain.volume = 1.0.)*

Code needs to work with iOS mobile Safari webkit.

**CSS included:**

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**HTML Follows:**

```
   <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>Fading in a Soundcloud Track</h2>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS Follows:**

```
    <script>
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext ||
                window.webAudioContext ||
                window.webkitAudioContext)();

        var audio = new Audio();
        var url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/179612876/stream' + '?client_id=<MY_ID>';

        audio.src = url;
        audio.preload = true;
        audio.load();

        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
            var currTime = audioCtx.currentTime;
            var duration = 30;
            var fadeTime = 6;

            var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
            gainNode.gain.value = 0.0;

            var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);

            source.connect(gainNode);
            gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

            // Then fade in
            gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0, currTime);
            gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1.0, currTime + fadeTime);
            // Then fade it out.
            gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1.0, currTime + duration-fadeTime);
            gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0, currTime + duration);

            //source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

            source.mediaElement.play();

            },false);

    </script>
```

Comment: FYI, I got it to work in chrome, but for some strange reason it doesn't in safari.

Answer (score 1):

"gainNode.gain.value = 0.0;" doesn't actually set a schedule point in the scheduler, it just sets the current value.  Since there's no start point in the scheduler, it's jumping up when it hits the first schedule point (i.e. at time currTime + fadeTime).  Try this:

```
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.0, currTime);
        gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1.0, currTime + fadeTime);
        // Then fade it out.
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1.0, currTime + duration-fadeTime);
        gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0, currTime + duration);
```

(and don't bother setting gain.gain.value).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck - gainNode still seems to be bypassed.

Comment: Oh!  Duh.  You're trying to load audio content cross-domain; you can't get a cross-domain createMediaElementSource to work, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, why does it work perfectly in Chrome and not Safari / mobile Safari (iOS), as per rajmathan's comment above?

Comment: Last I checked, soundcloud serves audio files cross-domain (They put the right header in the response), but you should double check. I recently fixed Firefox so that it's compliant (it was broken before my patch), grab a Nightly or Developer Edition, and let us know ! Also you need to add the attribute "audio.crossOrigin = anonymous;" so that the request is made Cross-Origin.

Comment: I'm really stuck - I've had no luck getting this to work with mobile safari.  Is what I'm doing possible on iOS?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If createMediaElementSource isn't working because of CORS, I do remember seeing errors in the console.